# laravel fetch data from table with to foreign keys to the same table

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables:
teams with id, group_id and name
games with id, home_team_id, away_team_id, date and score

As you can see in my games table there are two foreign keys (home_team_id and away_team_id) pointing to the same table (teams).
How can I map those relations with laravel eloquent?
I tried this, but failed:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }

    public function games(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Game');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    public function homeTeam(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'home_team_id');
    }

    public function awayTeam(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'away_team_id');
    }

    public function bets(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Bet');
    }
}
```

In my view I want to call home_team->name and away_team->name:

```
<td>{{ $game->homeTeam->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $game->awayTeam->name }}</td>
```

I get this error:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

and

Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: /home/vagrant/Code/em/resources/views/schedule/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the relationship from the methods. For example:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'home_team_id');
```

You do that in your Team model, but not the game model.

Comment: in other words, if there's no `return $someval`, the returned value is `null`, which means the parent calls are effectively `$game->null->whatever`

Comment: well, that was really stupid. Sorry for wasting your time.. clearly that was the fault. thanks!